# Symfony 3 - FMElfinderBundle - Unable to upload documents other than images

Tags: symfony

I have no problem uploading images but when I tried to upload document like pdf, doc or xls, I have the following error

> Unable to upload "Document.pdf". File type not allowed

My config file

```
ivory_ck_editor:
    default_config: default
    configs:
        default:
            toolbar: standard
            filebrowserBrowseRoute: elfinder
            filebrowserBrowseRouteParameters: []

fm_elfinder:
    #assets_path: / # default is /assets, this is where css/js elfinder files are
    instances:
        default:
            locale: %locale% # defaults to current request locale
            editor: ckeditor # other options are tinymce, tinymce4, fm_tinymce, form, simple, custom
            #editor_template: custom template for your editor # default null
            #path_prefix: / # for setting custom assets path prefix, useful for non vhost configurations, i.e. http://127.0.0.1/mysite/
            #fullscreen: true|false # default is true, applies to simple and ckeditor editors
            #theme: smoothness # jquery theme, default is 'smoothness'
            include_assets: true # disable if you want to manage loading of javascript and css assets manually
            #visible_mime_types: ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg'] # only show these mime types, defaults to show all
            connector:
                #debug: true|false # defaults to false
                roots:       # at least one root must be defined, defines root filemanager directories
                    uploads:
                        #show_hidden: true|false # defaults to false, hides dotfiles
                        driver: LocalFileSystem
                        path: uploads
                        upload_allow: ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg','text/txt', 'document/pdf', 'document/docx', 'document/xlsx']
                        upload_deny: ['all']
                        upload_max_size: 10M # also file upload sizes restricted in php.ini
```

I have changed upload_allow setting.

How can I upload pdf, doc or xls files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if found this site http://mime.ritey.com/ which helps me to find out the mime type of a file. If editor is ckeditor, there is no need to change the upload_allow because it insert any file as an image.

We have to add a form instance to fm_elfinder with editor: form

```
fm_elfinder:
    instances:
        default:
            locale: %locale% 
            editor: ckeditor 
            include_assets: true
            connector:
                roots:       
                    uploads:
                        driver: LocalFileSystem
                        path: uploads
                        upload_allow: ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg']
                        upload_deny: ['all']
                        upload_max_size: 10M 
        form:
            locale: %locale% 
            editor: form 
            fullscreen: true 
            include_assets: true 
            connector:
                debug: false 
                roots:       
                    uploads:
                        driver: LocalFileSystem
                        path: uploads
                        upload_allow: ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'application/pdf', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet']
                        upload_deny: ['all']
                        upload_max_size: 10M
```

and I add the mime type of PDF, Word, Excel and Powerpoint files.

and the form is

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Ivory\CKEditorBundle\Form\Type\CKEditorType;
use FM\ElfinderBundle\Form\Type\ElFinderType;

class PublicationType extends AbstractType
{  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
      $builder
        ->add('title', TextType::class)
        ->add('document', ElFinderType::class, array('instance'=>'form', 'enable'=>true))
        ->add('description', CKEditorType::class, array(
          'required' => false, 'empty_data'  => null))
        ->add('content', FileType::class)
        ->add('publicationDate', DateType::class, array(
              'years' => range(date('Y')-15, date('Y'))
              ))
      ;
  }
```

with ElFinderType, I can upload any kind of file